# reformat XAML in VS 2013 or with Resharper

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, reformat

I have several question about formatting XAML code with Resharper or VS 2013.

- How can I set up in Resharper Code Cleanup or in VS add empty line
     between XAML / XML tags?

**Before:**

```
<Canvas Background = "LightSkyBlue">
    <TextBox x:Name = "TextBoxGreen"
             Canvas.Left = "150"
             Canvas.Top = "50"
             MinWidth = "200"
             BorderThickness = "3"
             BorderBrush = "GreenYellow"
             MouseDown = "TextBox_OnMouseDown">
        Text from green textBox
    </TextBox>
</Canvas>
```

**After**

```
<Canvas Background = "LightSkyBlue">

    <TextBox x:Name = "TextBoxGreen"
             Canvas.Left = "150"
             Canvas.Top = "50"
             MinWidth = "200"
             BorderThickness = "3"
             BorderBrush = "GreenYellow"
             MouseDown = "TextBox_OnMouseDown">
        Text from green textBox
    </TextBox>

</Canvas>
```

- I would like order XAML attributes in logical order or alphabetical
        order. After my research I found these options:

  - Use [Xaml Markup Styler Extension](http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/) but not useful for me because I
       use VS 2013. Port to [VS 2013](http://xamlformatter2013.codeplex.com/) is not finish yet.
  - Use [Xaml Attribute Ordering Plugin to Resharper](https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/XamlAttributeOrderingCodeCleanup) but this plugin
    doesn’t order      event handlers for example.
- So it exist way how order XAML attributes in alphabetical order? Or how you order XAML attributes?

Answer (score 1):

select your code, and press

```
Alt+Enter
```

and select

```
Format Selection
```

Answer (score 0):

i think is too late for this answer but the solutions is quite simple. The shortcut keys are: CTRL + K + D in VS2013. that´s the middle of the question.

I hope it's useful.